# Search box with multiple terms

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I'm implementing a live search in a Chrome app (no cross-browser magic required), and have separated the search functionality out into its own module. I want the user to be able to enter multiple search terms by pressing the `/` key. Eventually I'll style it so it looks like a single text box, but when the user presses the `/` key, it puts the previous term into a its own box (a bit like the tag boxes on this site). I haven't implemented the part (separate module, maybe?) which actually does the searching, just the part which allows the user to enter their search terms. As I'm new to Angular, I'd appreciate some comments on my code structure.

I'm currently using `contenteditable` boxes in the template for the individual terms, which requires some additional logic to move the caret to the start/end of each box when switching between boxes. I've put the logic to bind the ngModel to the contenteditable boxes in a separate module, and I'm happy with that bit.

So a simple controller and model:

```
search.controller("searchController", ["$scope", "SearchTerms",
  function ($scope, SearchTerms) {
    $scope.query = SearchTerms.get();
  }]);

search.service("SearchTerms", function () {
  var terms = [""]; // initialise with one empty term
  return {
    get : function () {
      return terms;
    }
  };
});
```

And the monster directive which gets it all done:

```
search.directive("mySearch", ["$compile", function($compile) {
    return {
      templateUrl : "components/search/search-template.html",
      link : link,
      scope : {
        searchTerms : "=mySearch"
      }
    };
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      $compile(element.children());
      element.on("keydown", function (event) {
        var specialKeys = {
              8 : kbdBackspace,
              13 : kbdReturn,
              37 : kbdLeftArrow,
              38 : kbdUpArrow,
              39 : kbdRightArrow,
              40 : kbdDownArrow,
              191 : kbdSlash
            };
        if (!specialKeys.hasOwnProperty(event.keyCode)) {
          return;
        }
        if (specialKeys[event.keyCode](angular.element(event.target), scope)) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      }).on("click", function (event) {
        if (element.children(event.target).length) {
          return;
        }
      });
      function kbdBackspace(target) {
        var index = element.children("span").index(event.target);
        if (target.prop("selectionStart") === 0) {
          target.prev().focus().prop("selectionStart", target.text().length);
          if (scope.searchTerms.length > 1) {
            scope.searchTerms.splice(index, 1);
          }
          scope.$apply();
          return true;
        }
      }
      function kbdDownArrow(event) {
        // to do
      }
      function kbdLeftArrow(target) {
        if (target.prop("selectionStart") === 0) {
          target.prev().focus().prop("selectionStart", target.text().length);
          return true;
        }
      }
      function kbdReturn(target) {
        // to do
      }
      function kbdRightArrow(target) {
        console.log(target.prop("selectionStart"));
        if (selection() === target.val().length) {
          target.next().focus().prop("selectionStart", 0);
          return true;
        }
      }
      function kbdSlash(target, scope) {
        var index = element.children("span").index(target);
        scope.searchTerms.splice(index + 1, 0, "");
        scope.$apply();
        target.next().focus().prop("selectionStart", 0);
        return true;
      }
      function kbdUpArrow(event) {
        // to do
      }
    }
  }]);
```

The problems I can see are:

1. The directive feels too monolithic. Should some of the logic be separated out to somewhere else, and if so, where?
2. <strike>Related to that, it's all too tightly coupled to using contenteditables. What if I wanted to change to using inputs? I'd have to change the `range`/`selection` logic to `selectionStart` (which would be simpler, but I'd ideally not want to faff about with it at that stage).</strike>

**Edit:** I've implemented this in my contenteditable directive to make them act more like inputs, so this seems to solve problem 2.

```
  Object.defineProperties(element[0], {
    "selectionStart" : {
      set : function (val) {
        var range,
            selection;
        range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element[0]);
        range.collapse(!val); // only start or end works at the moment
        selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
      },
      get : function () {
        return window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).endOffset;
      }
    },
    "value" : {
      get : function () {
        return element.text();
      },
      set : function (val) {
        element.text(val);
      }
    }
  });
```

I've amended the search directive code above to reflect this. Assuming I can fix the problem that it only works at the start or end, what do you think of this approach? I think that the directive could still do with thinning out somehow though.